# Confirm Sending Email Using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, email

when I send email using STMP in C#, I can't make sure that the email has been send although I have used `SendCompleted` Event Handler. this is my code:

```
    private void btnLogin1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MailAddress FromAddress = new MailAddress("*******", "*******");
            MailAddress ToAddress = new MailAddress("*****");
            String FromPassword = "******";

            SmtpClient SMTP = new SmtpClient();
            SMTP.Host = "smtp.yandex.com";
            SMTP.Port = 587;
            SMTP.EnableSsl = true;
            SMTP.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            SMTP.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            SMTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromAddress.Address, FromPassword);
            SMTP.SendCompleted += SMTP_SendCompleted;

            MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
            Message.From = FromAddress;
            Message.To.Add(ToAddress);
            Message.Subject = "Welcome";
            Message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            Message.Body = "<b>Test Mail</b>";
            Message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            SMTP.Send(Message);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void SMTP_SendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sent");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That event is only triggered when you send it asynchronously. When your code gets past the `SMPT.Send(Message);` you should assume the mail was sent. I say assume, because you can never be truly sure an email will arrive after all.

Comment: Wouldn't that be SMTP.SendAsync()?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said 'when you send it asynchronously'?

Comment: I removed your credential information from the question for you, but you should really be more careful about that in the future.

Comment: please remove your comment as fast as you could as I have entered personal information in my post

Comment: thanks alooooooot can you remove them to from the edits

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Here you go, check this out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275837/is-there-a-way-to-hide-edit-history-of-question

Comment: can you remove this post for me as my information still shown in the edit history

Comment: You should be able to delete your own question. Maybe that's only if there are no answers yet? Of course, people with high enough rep can see deleted questions anyway. Best to get a mod to fix the history and change your password.

Comment: @AhmedAlayat I flagged it for mod attention to remove it, but you should definitely change the pass

Comment: @alexander derck ... Sorry! Misread what you wrote there ;-)

Comment: I have upvoted this comment wrongly, and I have changed the pass

Answer (score 3):

You need to put some error handling code inside

```
Catch {...}
```

Otherwise, you are just catching an error and ignoring it.
If the catch block doesn't fire, then as far as you can be reasonably sure (without checking for a delivery receipt), then you can assume the email has been successfully sent.

Comment: Your point about swallowing exceptions is valid; but you should avoid making assumptions when writing code. Especially in OP's case where he's subscribing to the [SendCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event that only is raised when an email is sent asynchronously, but not calling [SendAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But he's not using SMTP.SendAsync()

Comment: Correct. That is the problem.

Comment: Agreed, unless he wants to send synchronously, which is the juxtapose assumption... :-D

Comment: I am using STMP... but don't know how to use sendAsync

Comment: You need to start a new question! But here's a starter ...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx .... You need to understand multithreading, thread blocking, async and await keywords. It's not going to be A 5 minute job.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `SendCompleted` event, then the email needs sent asynchronously using `SendAsync`. Otherwise, the method will not return control until after the email is either sent or fails.

In the example you posted, the empty catch is swallowing up any errors that may be occurring to even determine that much.

So either use the `SendAsync` so that your event gets fired, or actually see if any exceptions are being caught. Empty catch blocks that aren't even catching any specific exception are terrible ideas in nearly every situation. They lead to all sorts of problems.

Comment: how to use SendAsync

Comment: Pretty much the same as `Send`. Could start by looking at the documentation on MSDN... If you still have troubles, there are answered questions here on SO for reference.